# Button executando uma função em js e outra em php

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Boa tarde pessoal, estou com uma duvida teria como na hora que eu clicasse no button ele chamasse uma função em js e outra em php?

estou com um problema quero que uma variavel no caso $nome receba o valor que digitar num input e quando clicasse no botão faça a verificação com o db e retorne na mesma página os resultados,

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
   function fnome() {
   $nome = document.getElementById('nome').value;
  }
   
   
</script>
```

```html
<button onclick="fnome()">Pega</button>

 <?php 

  
  $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pedidos WHERE nome LIKE '%".$nome."%'");
  $row = mysql_num_rows($sql);
  if ($row > 0) {
   while ( $linha = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $id = $linha['id'];
    $nome = $linha['nome'];
    $pedido = $linha['pedido'];
    $valor = $linha['valor'];
    
    echo "<br><br>ID: ". @$id;
    echo "<br><strong>Nome: </strong>". @$nome;
    echo "<br>Pedido: ". @$pedido;
    echo "<br>Valor: ". @$valor ;
    
   }
  }
  else {
   echo "Desculpe nenhum pedido foi encontrado!";
  }
 
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Então Samuel, acho que da forma que você deseja não é possível, pois o JavaScript e o PHP vão tentar serem executados ao mesmo tempo, o mais fácil a se fazer é fazer a verificação que você deseja via JavaScript.

Alocar esse código do PHP em outro arquivo e chamar ele via AJAX dentro do JavaScript depois de fazer a verificação que você deseja, aqui tem um tutorial para te ajudar com o AJAX:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

O resumo do que eu te recomendo a fazer é: Alocar a função do PHP em outro arquivo, fazer no index.html ou index.alguma_coisa e chamar o arquivo do PHP via AJAX depois de você executar a validação que deseja com o JS.

Se não ficou claro é só avisar :)
Abraços!

Comment: passei para o arquivo php, mas na hora do ajax estou com muita dificuldade, esse arquivo está retornando em echo, não sei se é possivel retornar os valores em uma grid ou table, pelo que entendi no ajax, tem que passar os valores para uma id no html, como ficaria em uma table ou grid os valores retornados?

Comment: O ajax faz o envio de um objeto, dai nesse objeto você coloca o que desejar, e você lê ele no PHP como desejar também, rs, só recomendo que decodifique ele de JSON para o PHP com alguma função nativa do PHP que deve existir.